# Can I get TCP flags from lsof output?

Tags: tcp, flags, darwin, lsof

I'm trying to obtain Network traffic data from lsof. I'm trying to see the TCP flags, but I don't find it.

I've tried the following, as indicated by the man pages for BSD:

`lsof -Tf`

`lsof -i`

`lsof +fg`

None of these seem to give TCP flags.

The man pages seem to indicate that it is possible to obtain TCP flags, using the `-T` option.  See the excerpt from [the man pages for lsof(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lsof&sektion=8&manpath=linux)  below.

```
-T with following characters selects the reporting of specific
TCP/TPI information:

     f    selects reporting of socket options,
      states and values, and TCP flags and
      values.
     q    selects queue length reporting.
     s    selects connection state reporting.
     w    selects window size reporting.
```

But, these don't seem to work. My operating system is Darwin, and I'm trying to run it in bash.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "TCP flags"? Do you mean the flags on a TCP packet (like SYN, RST, PSH)? If so, what does that have to do with `lsof` which has nothing to do with packets?

Comment: You seem to be just trying things at random instead of reading the documentation.

Comment: I've used the following page to get the documentation: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lsof&sektion=8&manpath=linux It states: "-T with following characters selects the reporting of specific TCP/TPI information: f  selects reporting ... and TCP flags and values".  That is the reason why I'm trying what I said. According to it, I should be obtaining the TCP flags. But the output doesn't seem to be so.

Comment: The previous comment explains where I got the documentation from @EJP